# Opening files in CUDA C

Tags: c, file, fopen, fread

I am trying to open two files(linoteste.ima and sysmattest.dat) they both contain one matrix. After successfully opening the files, when I print them, I only get matrices containing zeros and I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is not a CUDA related problem but a C one, its just that I am opening the files to do matrix multiplication with CUDA. My code is as follows (I have tried replacing fread with a while cicle to read one element at a time, but it does not work):

```
    float*matlino=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*100*100);
float*matsys=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*10000*10000);

//Open linogram
FILE * flino, *fmat;
flino = fopen ("linoteste.ima","r");      //also tried with "rb" instead of "r"
if (flino!=NULL)
{
    fread (matlino,sizeof(float),100*100,flino);
    fclose (flino);
    puts("Linograma aberto com sucesso");
}
else
    puts("impossivel abrir linograma");
printMat(matlino,10,10);

//Open system matrix

fmat = fopen("sysmattest.dat","r"); 
if (fmat!=NULL)
{
    fread (matsys,sizeof(float),10000*10000,fmat);
    fclose (fmat);
    puts("Matriz sistema aberta com sucesso");
}
else
puts("impossivel abrir matriz sistema");
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps printMat() has a problem?

Comment: What os are you using?  Is flino NULL or is fread not getting the desired data?

Comment: How did you write the matrices out in the first place - the same way, as a dump of a float array? Are the files full of zeroes? (Yes, I expect you'd need "rb") What return value are you getting from fread?

Comment: what is CUDAish here? plain C

Comment: Yes i said it was not a CUDA related problem, is just that im working with CUDA. I guess i solved it, i didnt think it had so many zeros, i ran a program to count the number of zeros and indeed it has a lot of them. But should i use "rb" or just "r"?

Comment: @Bernardo: If your data is raw binary (as opposed to text), then you should use `"rb"`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried fscanf()?

Something like:

```
if(flino!=NULL)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) fscanf(flino, "%f", &malino[i]);
    fclose(flino);
}
```